# Different page templates for different nodes

Tags: drupal, templates

Using drupal 7 is great. The api is full of great ideas - although I miss some OPP sometimes.

Now I stuck on a problem with defining different page templates for different nodes.
After searching for this problem in the [official documentation](http://drupal.org/node/190815#page-suggestion) I found out that drupal uses suggestions to find templates like `page-node-nid.tpl.php`.

**My Situation:**

I have a page called "Skills" with the id 2. The url is `/skills` (don't know if this is important) and I have a template called `/templates/page-node-2.tpl.php`. But drupal doesn't load the file. I also try to rename the original `page.tpl.php` to see that I'm working in the right directory. Clearing the cache doesn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Hope you can help!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be an error in the documentation.   try  **page--node--2.tpl.php**  Note that there are 2 dashes rather than 1

That works for me in Drupal 7

Comment: Did anybody find this solution inside the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

- first, the alias (that is "skills in your case) isn't important
- Where exactly is your template located? It needs to be in the top-level directory of your theme, not in a templates subfolder.
- Not sure if that has been fixed in D7, but at least in D6, you also needed to have an page.tpl.php in your theme to have it pick up template suggestions?
- After adding the file, make sure that you rebuild the theme registry, devel.module works well, or re-saving the form admin/build/themes.